# (UInt16)i vs Convert.ToUInt16(i)

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `Int32` **which is within the bounds** of `UInt16`. Which method should I use to change it into an `UInt16`? Is there a reason to use one instead of the other or does it not matter? Any pitfalls (e.g. casting a `float` will truncate, converting will round)?

```
Int32 int32 = 2;
UInt16 a = (UInt16)int32;
UInt16 b = Convert.ToUInt16(int32);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [full source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs) for `Convert.ToUInt16(int value)` :

```
    [CLSCompliant(false)]   
    public static ushort ToUInt16(int value) {
        if (value < 0 || value > UInt16.MaxValue) 
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_UInt16"));
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return (ushort)value;
    }
```

Looks like it resolves to a cast anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToUInt16(int)` is implemented as:

```
public static ushort ToUInt16(int value)
{
    if (value < 0 || value > 65535)
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_UInt16"));
    }
    return (ushort)value;
}
```

As you can see, it's just checking the bounds before doing a direct cast.  So, if you *know* your integer is within the bounds of `UInt16`, then just cast and avoid the redundant check.

(I got the implementation by using ILSpy - its free)

Comment: @David784 how is it safer if it's doing the same thing as the cast?  also, you can't get a negative number if it's an unsigned short.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that Convert will throw an exception if the value is out of the range of the target type whereas the case will just lose information.

```
Int32 a = Int32.MaxValue;
UInt16 b = (UInt16)a;
Console.WriteLine(b); // Outputs 65535
UInt16 c = Convert.ToUInt16(a); // Throws OverflowException
```

Efficiency wise, inspecting the IL in LinqPad, there's no difference in the size of the code generated. Convert calls out to a class library method and the cast uses a native IL command and so is probably more efficient if less safe.